# Can I find the current "Private Mode" setting for my account from the Vimeo API?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am comfortable with the Vimeo API and the API docs. I am looking through the API reference (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference), but I cannot find a way to verify my current configuration for "**Private Mode**". We recently had someone turn this off manually and I want to regularly check for the status via a script. If not via the API, is there another way to check programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Could you open a ticket with support (https://vimeo.com/help/contact) and reference this post?

This is information we can provide in the API when it's requested, but will need your account details to do so.